# How to remove unwated code from a php string?

Tags: php

I want replace text in a string using php in-built function, How do I accomplish this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of:

[`str_replace('look', 'replace', $context);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

[`preg_replace('pattern', 'replace', $context);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what text you want to replace, if you just want a very simple replace, you might find some success in the [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) function.

Of course without having an example of what it is exactly you want to remove, we can't give you a better answer. More complicated examples might require you to write a regular expression, and then use a string-replacement method that makes use of regular expressions like [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this example

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

More details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

with regards

**Wazzy**

Answer (score 0):

Your question title seems to suggest that you are interested in sanitizing a string. If this is the case, you could consider [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) if you wish to prevent HTML code from being rendered as such. If you are interested in sanitizing for database input, you might wish to consider `mysql_real_escape_string()` for a MySQL query.

Otherwise, as mentioned you can use `str_replace()` (or the case-insensitive version) to replace all instances of one string with another string.